# can not access appSetting section in c# xml configuration file

Tags: c#, configuration-files

I want to access the xml configuration file for adding information to it at runtime.
so I added configuration file and the file content is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings></appSettings>
</configuration>
```

and my code for accessing to appSetting section:

```cs
var configFile = new ConfigurationFileMap() { MachineConfigFilename = "CommonConfig.config" };
baseConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(configFile);
source = baseConfig.AppSettings;
```

but when execution reaches line 3 ( in above code) the exception will occur(which I added to title).

more information:
file name : CommonConfig .
app : .net core 3.1 classlibrary

Answer (score 0):

The `OpenMappedMachineConfiguration` is used to get access to the `machine.config` file. You should be using the `OpenMappedExeConfiguration` to acces that `CommonConfig.config`:

```cs
var configFile = new ExeConfigurationFileMap() { 
    ExeConfigFilename = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) ,"CommonConfig.config") 
};
baseConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFile, ConfigurationUserLevel.None); 
source = baseConfig.AppSettings;
```

Comment: Hi @sajad, I have edited your answer to explain why the code solves the problem so OP and others know not only the solution but also why it fixes the problem.